# Get all items from one model on condition that is in other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Hi i was snooping around stack but answers are confusing or not working, you can see my models how can I get all OrderItems made by user that have complete=True in Order.

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    customer        = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_oredred    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete        = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id  = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order       = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_id  = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```py
qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__complete=True)
```

To get for specific customer:

```py
qs.filter(order__customer=specific_customer)
```